# Refresh DocumentSnapshot after setData() without additional query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In order to set new data in a Firestore document, I normally use `setData()` with `merge: true`. This works fine and as intended regarding data saving:

```
await userDoc.reference.setData({
    'favourite_color': 'blue',
    'favourite_team': 'fcporto',
  },merge: true);
```

My only issue is that DocumentSnapshot (userDoc in this example) doesn't get automatically 'refreshed' after `setData` is finished, which forces me to do an additional query to the document.

Is there any way to automatically update DocumentSnapshot after setData() ? (same behaviour happens with `updateData()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, DocumentSnapshot objects are immutable - the can't be changed.  You will have to make another query, or wait for another realtime update from a listener.

Answer (score 0):

I have many places in my code where I have Listeners for document/documents, and I perform *completely separate* .set()s etc on them - the *Listeners* take care of updating my local copy of the document (whether by Redux or simply useState Hooks).  Not really a good idea to hold onto the DocumentSnapshot(s) - copy them to some form of local state.